# GIT is not installing in OEPE 11.1.1.8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, git, soa

How to upgrade Git on eclipse/OEPE on which it is not supported and I don't want to use juno or kepler. kindly help out on the issue
 I have used url  http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates to install git on eclipse , it is giving error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
  Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.4.1.201406201815-r) requires 'bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going to install new software and giving following URIs and mark these as checked 
after fetching complete. Git libraries are coming and I am able to install git on eclipse indego

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201106220900
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo